# inline code on server control properties

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, inline-code

I have a public POCO property (SiteDetail) on my page and I need to know what's the best approach when setting properties of server controls:

1. Use inline code and Page.DataBind(); on load

   `<asp:Label ID="lbName" runat="server" Text="<%# SiteDetail.Name %>"/`>
2. Do not use inline code and set control properties on page load

   `lbName.Text = SiteDetail.Name;`

Is it "dangerous" to use `Page.DataBind()` on load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So...I did some more research and found `Page.DataBind()` is not a good thing, is better to call DabaBind on every single control you need, as @Muhammad Akhtar says, both ways renders the same so I prefer to use inline code because it seems clearer, now I have

```
<asp:Label ID="lbName" runat="server" Text="<%# SiteDetail.Name %>"/>
```

and code behind:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
        lbName.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Can you give me reference where you found that, Calling Page.DataBind() is not good?

Comment: hmm, that's an issue to call Page.DataBind() method, but again if you call databind method label by label, that is again panic. In this way, you have to bind and then call databind method. But if you assign the text property in code behind, you have to do in one place and that is more code readable and there is less chance of erroneous.

Answer (score 1):

Did you see the rendered source? There is no difference at all. Both labels will render text in the span. Just perform a simple test and it will be clear to you.

here is what I have for a test

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#test %>'></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

here is generated source below.

```
 <span id="Label1">this text is from binding expression</span>
 <span id="Label2"><br/>this text set from code behind</span>
```

You will see no difference at all

Comment: yes, is the same rendering, I prefer to use inline code as it seems clearer for me, please see answer below, and than you ;)